# .htaccess file not working for query string in linux

Tags: .htaccess

I am using :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I want to open http://www.supportshack.com/chat/php/ajax.php?action=checkLogged"

```
Error coming : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found ".
```

can any one has a answer for this question ?

Comment: There is nothing in your .htaccess file to suggest why the URL with query string results in a 404. In fact, if your remove the query string and you get the same 404 error. (?)

Comment: can you tell what line of code , I shall write to get rid of my problem

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your question what the problem is. Does `/chat/php/ajax.php` exist on your filesystem (I assume it should and not be routed through `index.php`)?

Comment: yes , /chat/php/ajax.php exist on my filesystem.

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.supportshack.com/chat/php/ajax.php?action=getChats&lastID=0"
ajax.ph...astID=0
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.supportshack.com/chat/php/ajax.php?action=getUsers"
ajax.ph...etUsers
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.supportshack.com/chat/php/ajax.php?action=checkLogged"

Comment: working on localhost , but not in server

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Do you have any other .htaccess files in subdirectories?

Comment: a subdirectory (.htaccess) exists , written   Order deny,allow
Deny from all  . but i think this does not effect.

Comment: If that .htaccess file is in this _filesystem_ path (ie. `/chat/.htaccess` or `/chat/php/.htaccess`) then that is definitely a problem and will block all access! However, this would ordinarily trigger a 403 Forbidden, not a 404 - although your system could be configured to send 404s instead?

Comment: something like yhis RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]

Comment: . /chat/.htaccess or /chat/php/.htaccess not exists

Comment: What is that `RewriteRule` referring to? If there is nothing else in your .htaccess file and you have no other .htaccess files in the filesystem path and the file definitely exists then... _something's messed up_! Maybe your server config (although is that really a possibility)? Is it some obscure mod_security rule?! Is it your code? However, you have all the debugging tools at your end to see how/where/when this error is being triggered. Unfortunately I'm running out of "wild guesses".

Comment: You seem to be pursuing the "query string" idea, however, that URL fails (in the same way) when you omit the query string (as stated in my first comment). So, if the file does exist, that would seem to suggest that it is your `ajax.php` file that is triggering this error? [/chat/php/ajax.php](http://www.supportshack.com/chat/php/ajax.php) (no query string).